# oracle: creating new jobs and running them

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How could I check if I have privileges to create a oracle job? Is there any query to find this out and help me out in creating an oracle job that should run on every last Saturday of each and every month.

Answer (score 2):

You need CREATE JOB privilege. More info in official documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI